# Bash script to find files in a list, copy them to dest, print files not found

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like to build on the answer I found here: [Bash script to find specific files in a hierarchy of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269455/bash-script-to-find-specific-files-in-a-hierarchy-of-files)

```
find $dir -name $name -exec scp {} $destination \;
```

I have a file with a list of file names and I need to find those files on a backup disk, then copy those files found to a destination folder, and lastly print the files that could not be found to a new file.

the last step would be helpful so that I wouldn't need to make another list of files copied and then do a compare with original list.

If the script can then make a list of the copied files, and do a compare, then print the differences, then that's exactly what's required. Unless the shell process find can print to file each time it "Can't find" a file.

Comment: Maybe build something with `rsync`, it can do the `only copy files that have changed` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your list is separated by newlines; something like this should work

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=someWhere
dest=someWhereElse
toCopyList=filesomewhere
notCopied=filesomewhereElse

while read line; do
   find "$dir" -name "$line" -exec cp '{}' $dest \; -printf "%f\n"     
done < "$toCopyList" > cpList

#sed -i 's#'$dir'/##' cpList
# I used # instead of / in sed to not confuse sed with / in $dir
# Also, I assumed the string in $dir doesnot end with a /

cat cpList "$toCopyList" | sort | uniq -c | sed -nr '/^ +1/s/^ +1 +(.*)/\1/p' > "$notCopied"
# Will not work if you give wild cards in your "toCopyList"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried your script and it returns this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
find: paths must precede expression: 66

Comment: Looks like find and sed doesn't like each other :). Could you try removing the sed part and add this after the `done < toCopyList` line.

`sed -i 's#^'$dir'/##' cpList`

Comment: Editing the answer to fix the problem with find and sed pipe

Comment: now it gives an error: `find: paths must precede expression: 1205_60.jpg` (caused by space in file name) and also `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated s' command`

Comment: Could you change the `find` line to this `find $dir -name "$line" -exec cp '{}' $dest \; -printf "%f\n"` and try. Also comment out the `sed` line as it is no longer needed

Comment: If you have un-escaped spaces in your file names; the last line also will not work. Try changing the `awk` part to something like this `sed -nr '/^ +1/s/^ +1 +(.*)/\1/p'` ( I hope you have the GNU version of `sed`. The `-r` flag is not there in all versions )

Comment: finally the missed file names are printed in the notCopied file! I used your new `find` line, including `"$dir"` as directory had spaces in name.  Then the `awk` line printed to notCopied but only part before spaces in file names.  Changing to the new `sed` line fixed that. well done and thanks for the effort!

Comment: I also add at top `toCopyList=/dir/of/tocopy/list` then within the script I use `"$toCopyList"` and that works fine.  pls ammend your script above if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read fname ; do
  find /FROM/WHERE/TO/COPY/ \
       -type f \
       -name "$fname" \
       -exec cp \{\} /DESTINATION/DIR/ \; 2>/dev/null 
  find /DESTINATION/DIR/ \
       -type f \
       -name "$fname" &>/dev/null || \
       echo $fname
done < FILESTOCOPY > MISSEDFILES
```

Will do.

Comment: I must be missing something because with this all I get is an instant filling of MISSEDFILES with my FILESTOCOPY list (using other file names obviously) and the external disk is not being searched (where I run the script from).  FILESTOCOPY is a list of file names w/o file location so I need files of same name on other file system to be found.

Comment: Now that works well, and its fast.  Thanks for helping me, Zsolt

Comment: except I missed that files are not printing out, I forgot to test with a dummy filename.  I tried echo "$fname" and still not printing.

Comment: Filenames are in the MISSEDFILES file like you specified: "print the files that could not be found to a new file."

Comment: yes, they do not print in that file, sorry I wasn't clear about that.
`done < /media/FILES/my\ pictures/copylist > /media/FILES/my\ pictures/missed`

Comment: Updated with searching for copied file.

Comment: still no print into file, and I would have thought that the 2nd find needs to find files from the copy list that are _not_ there in destination, not files that _are_ there.